# Including headers in an Xcode 4.2.1 project

Tags: xcode, opengl, soil

I'm trying to use a library, specifically SOIL (Simple OpenGL Image Library) in Xcode 4.2.1. Under Build Phases -> Link Library with Libraries I add all the .h and .c files that came with the SOIL zip archive.

When I build the project, I get the following error message for every .h and .c file added:

> warning: skipping file '/Users/saw/XcodeProjects/Assignment01 copy/Assignment01/image_DXT.c' 
>   (unexpected file type 'sourcecode.c.c' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)

and a linker error:

> "_SOIL_load_OGL_texture", referenced from: Init() in main.o Symbol(s)
>   not found for architecture x86_64 Clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 9):

.h and .c files aren't libraries.  Add the .c files to the compile phase and just `#import` the .h files where needed.

To verify linking I have done the following:

- Create a new Mac Cocoa application.
- Add 10 files from the SOIL `src`
  folder: SOIL.c, image_DXT.h, stbi_DDS_aug.h, SOIL.h, image_helper.c,
  stb_image_aug.c, stbi_DDS_aug_c.h, image_DXT.c, image_helper.h, and
  stb_image_aug.h.
- Tell Xcode to copy them to my project.
- Add one line
  to my app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method:
  `SOIL_load_OGL_texture( "img_test.png", SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
  SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, 0 );`.
- Build the target for running.

Although there are a variety of compiler warnings about data conversion, these steps produce an executable with no linker errors.

Comment: I have have added the files in the correct way unlike @Terribad it seems. The error still remains

Comment: I assume you mean the linker error as opposed to the "skipping file" message?  Can you find `SOIL_load_OGL_texture` defined inside one of the files that are being built (SOIL.c for example)?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding -framework to your framework's name in the "Other Linker Flags" such as:

```
-framework SOIL
```